# AppEngine / OS X - vendor.add('lib') just not working? (plus partial solution)

Tags: python, google-app-engine, flask

I've been experimenting with GAE, and struggling to get [Google's flask example](https://cloud.google.com/appengine/docs/standard/python/getting-started/python-standard-env) working with dev_appserver.py.  Despite using the simple code given, I was receiving the dreaded 'ImportError: No module named flask' error.  (It did work via the flask server, if needed, tho' obviously this didn't help.)

This is despite having flask (and all related dependencies) installed in the /lib sub-folder of my project folder, and despite the (supposedly) correct code in appengine_config.py (see all below).  I also tried multiple small variations of these files, to no avail.

---

THEN... I saw [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10561387/google-appengine-error-no-module-named-flask/14248647#14248647), and tried just copying all of the contents of *projectfolder/* lib/python/site-packages into *projectfolder/*  ... and now it seems to work perfectly.

Can anyone see what am I missing (as I'd prefer to have the neat folder structure as advertised)?  Or is this a GAE bug, as it seems that vendor.add just isn't doing what it should?

---

**app.yaml**

```
runtime: python27
api_version: 1
threadsafe: true

handlers:
- url: /.*
  script: main.app
```

**main.py**

```
import logging
from flask import Flask, render_template, request

app = Flask('test')

@app.route('/')
def hello():
    return 'Hello World!'
```

**appengine_config.py**

```
from google.appengine.ext import vendor

print "*** appengine_config ***"     # Just to see if/when it's being run

# Add any libraries installed in the "lib" folder.
vendor.add('lib')
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Make sure all your libraries are installed using pip into `app/lib` (assuming `app` is your project name), delete the sub-folder `app/lib/lib` and re-run.

**Explanation**:

If you look at the `vendor.py` code from Google here, there is a hint: https://cloud.google.com/appengine/docs/standard/python/refdocs/modules/google/appengine/ext/vendor

The relevant portion is this:

```
venv_path = os.path.join(path, 'lib', PYTHON_VERSION, 'site-packages')
if os.path.isdir(venv_path):
    site_dir = venv_path
elif os.path.isdir(path):
    site_dir = path
```

So the `appengine_config.py` file first tries to look in  `project_folder/lib/python2.7/site-packages`. That is the state of your current configuration. For a cleaner code base you want to be hitting the `elif` branch of that code.

I had this problem a while ago. I was using `vendor.add('lib')` in the `appengine_config.py` file and storing all my necessary 3rd party libraries there. Then at some point I did a pip install using an incorrect installation prefix and it had ended up creating the folder `lib/python2.7/site-packages` inside my `app/lib` folder. So the App Engine environment ended up finding all the libraries that I had installed with the incorrect pip installation, but none of the libraries which were in the `app/lib` folder itself. I just had to delete the folder `app/lib/lib`, re-do the pip install for the incorrectly installed libraries, and everything worked again.

Hope this helps solve your problem.

Comment: Partly - and it helped me figure out the problem - so thanks!  The problem was that the configuration of the path within the main app folder was actually `lib/lib/python/site-packages`, when it should have been `lib/lib/python2.7/site-packages`.  It's not ideal to have to manually change it to `python2.7` as the original path was the one made by PIP when installing the local copies of the packages.  But at least it works.

Comment: Or, of course, `vendor.add('lib/lib/python/site-packages')` points it right to the correct original folder.

Answer (score 0):

I found the answer for myself here : https://cloud.google.com/appengine/docs/standard/python/tools/using-libraries-python-27#vendoring

I had to replace `vendor.add('lib')` with this more explicit version and it resolved the issue immediately :

```
vendor.add(os.path.join(os.path.dirname(os.path.realpath(__file__)), 'lib'))
```