# ImportError: No module named flask on google app engine

Tags: python, google-app-engine, flask, virtualenv

I'm following this [tutorial](http://f.souza.cc/2010/08/flying-with-flask-on-google-app-engine.html) and I'm trying to develop a basic Flask app to run on the Google App Engine. I am using Windows and have followed the guide exactly at every step.

1. I have set up my Virtual Environment and tested if flask was in it using the `import sys` in the virtual environment interpreter and it is there. simpleJson, Werkzeug, and Jinja2 are also there. I installed them using `pip install` in the virtual environment.
2. After checking the logs I only get a `<type 'exceptions.ImportError'>` saying:

> ```
> <type 'exceptions.ImportError'>: No module named flask 
>       args = ('No module named flask',) 
>       message = 'No module named flask'
> ```

1. This is my folder structure:

> ```
> gae/
>    /app/
>       __init__.py
>       models.py
>       settings.py
>       views.py
>    /venv/
>          /Include
>          /Lib
>          /Scripts
>    /flask/
>    /simplejson/
>    /werkzeug/
>    /jinja2/
>
>    app.yaml
>    main.py
> ```

I have read different questions here and googled similar issues, but after trying several possible solutions, I am still not able to fix it. At this point I don't know what I am missing, I am new to flask and GAE. Any suggestion on what I am doing wrong? Thanks in advance.

This is my **init**.py:

```
from flask import Flask
import settings

app = Flask('app')
app.config.from_object('app.settings')

import views
```

This is my app.yaml:

```
application: app
version: 1
runtime: python
api_version: 1

handlers:
- url: .*
  script: main.py
```

This is how my requirements.txt looks:

```
Flask==0.9  
Jinja2==2.6 
Werkzeug==0.8.3 
simplejson==3.0.7
```

This is my main.py:

```
from google.appengine.ext.webapp.util
import run_wsgi_app from app import app

run_wsgi_app(app)
```

Comment: See [this example](http://mostovenko.blogspot.ro/2012/08/launching-flask-on-google-app-engine-gae.html). Maybe it helps

Comment: could you dump your requiremets of your virualenv. pip freeze > requirements.txt

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Look my answer to a similar question, explaining step by step how to run Python, Flask, Virtualenv and Google App Engine on Windows and verify if you are doing on same way:
[Can't import Flask while using Google App Engine](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10151294/cant-import-flask-while-using-google-app-engine/14248871#14248871)

Comment: thanks for your suggestion. I following your post update, however, still I get the same error. I did a `pip freeze > requirements.txt` and this are these are the listed libraries: Flask==0.9, Jinja2==2.6, Werkzeug==0.8.3, simplejson==3.0.7

Comment: I have updated my original post to reflect the changes I made based on your suggestion. Please let me know if there is any other info I should provide you with. Thanks!

Comment: Could you add the main.py file?

Comment: Thanks Max, I have update the original post with the main.py. It is at the end of the post. Thanks in advance.

Comment: Please, try move the app.yaml and main.py to inside the gae folder.

Comment: Sorry, it looks like app.yaml and main.py are not inside the gae folder from my post. I have updated the post, and in my computer they are in there. So both app.yaml and main.py are inside the gae folder. I have some additional things but still it doesn't start, I keep on getting the same error.

Comment: I have tried to do a simple basic `hello world` app and I keep on getting the same problem.

Comment: @lv10, This is really strange, I created the same structure here and this is working well. Are you running the application from Google App Engine Launcher? Maybe because of you are using the venv directory is causing a problem to run the application. If possible contact me on skype and I can help more.

Comment: Yes I am using Google App Launcher. I just added you on Skype. Thank you very much.

Comment: thanks. After removing the venv and testing for basic `hello world` it works now. Thanks Max!

Answer (score 0):

visit link given below; its a boilerplate project template for running a Flask-based application on Google App Engine (Python)
https://github.com/kamalgill/flask-appengine-template

Comment: Does the file structure has to be: `root/src/`? or could it be just `root/'contents of the src folder from the project template'`?

Answer (score -1):

Try sticking a blank **init**.py file in the root gae directory, then make your import:

```
from gae.flask import Flask
```

Comment: thanks, I tried your suggestion but still I get the same error.