# GCP could not find flask when it is present in lib folder

Tags: python, google-app-engine, google-cloud-platform, pip

I am trying to deploy a python flask app to GCP by following the standard guideline I have installed my requirements.txt to the lib folder using command

```
 pip install -t lib -r requirements.txt
```

but the server is failing at runtime with ImportError for flask module this is hapoening both locally and on cloud ie with

```
dev_appserver.py  app.yaml #locally
gcloud app deploy # On cloud
```

but when I open the lib folder I could see the dependency there

Here is what my requirements.txt looks like

```
requests>=2.19.1
pandas==0.20.3
python-telegram-bot==11.1.0
Quandl>=3.4.0
redis
stockstats==0.2.0
flask
flask-socketio
python-socketio
flask-login
```

Comment: might be related to: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14273149/importerror-no-module-named-flask-on-google-app-engine#14307599 where a guy points to his examples on: https://github.com/kamalgill/flask-appengine-template

Comment: @AdamLazaruso yes that is being goes as part of my code , do I need to mention it somewhere ?

Comment: @AdamLazaruso added to the question

Comment: Can you share your `app.yaml` and the full traceback?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1 - Do you have the file `appengine_config.py`

with the following 2 lines:

```
from google.appengine.ext import vendor
vendor.add('lib')
```

https://cloud.google.com/appengine/docs/standard/python/tools/using-libraries-python-27

2 - does your `lib` folder have a `__init__.py` in it