# No modules named flask (GAE)

Tags: python, google-app-engine, flask

I'm trying to run the vanilla gae-init project here https://github.com/gae-init/gae-init/ to start playing around with Flask and GAE. I keep getting this error -

```
INFO     2015-10-11 13:28:25,924 devappserver2.py:763] Skipping SDK update check.
INFO     2015-10-11 13:28:26,001 api_server.py:205] Starting API server at: http://localhost:48281
INFO     2015-10-11 13:28:26,024 dispatcher.py:197] Starting module "default" running at: http://127.0.0.1:8080
INFO     2015-10-11 13:28:26,026 admin_server.py:116] Starting admin server at: http://localhost:8081
ERROR    2015-10-11 13:28:28,552 wsgi.py:263] 
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/media/thomas/2CCC2F86CC2F4982/Dev Stuff/SDKs/google_appengine/google/appengine/runtime/wsgi.py", line 240, in Handle
    handler = _config_handle.add_wsgi_middleware(self._LoadHandler())
  File "/media/thomas/2CCC2F86CC2F4982/Dev Stuff/SDKs/google_appengine/google/appengine/runtime/wsgi.py", line 299, in _LoadHandler
    handler, path, err = LoadObject(self._handler)
  File "/media/thomas/2CCC2F86CC2F4982/Dev Stuff/SDKs/google_appengine/google/appengine/runtime/wsgi.py", line 85, in LoadObject
    obj = __import__(path[0])
  File "/media/thomas/2CCC2F86CC2F4982/Linux/Python/gae-init/main/main.py", line 3, in <module>
    import flask
ImportError: No module named flask
INFO     2015-10-11 13:28:28,560 module.py:786] default: "GET /_ah/warmup HTTP/1.1" 500 749
```

I've tried adding the `PYTHONPATH` to my .bashrc file with `export PYTHONPATH=$PYTHONPATH:/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages` (dist-packages because that's where pip seems to be installing all my stuff? I saw mentions of `site-packages`, but there's nothing in that folder)

I've tried running `pip install -r requirements.txt -t lib` because as far as I can tell, dev_server.py cannot find flask at all.

I've checked out answers [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14273149/importerror-no-module-named-flask-on-google-app-engine) and [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10151294/cant-import-flask-while-using-google-app-engine/14248871#14248871) but they didn't help much. The second one seems promising, but I'm running Ubuntu and not Windows.

I'm quite a beginner with Python so trying to figure this out as I go along.

Thanks for any help!

Comment: When it comes to gae-init though.. all you have to do is to fulfill the [requirements](http://docs.gae-init.appspot.com/requirement/) and then run `gulp`...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You have to tell your app where third-party libraries are by adding `appengine_config.py` to your project root.

https://cloud.google.com/appengine/docs/python/tools/libraries27#vendoring

Comment: https://cloud.google.com/appengine/docs/standard/python/tools/built-in-libraries-27 On this page I see that  flask 0.12 is included in the appengine runtime. Does this mean I still have to add it to my vendor lib?